# jQuery append variable array

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, append

How can I grab a value from an array and call it within `.append()`?

In this code, the array I'm trying to pull content from is `titles`, and append it to the list item with the class `.activeSlide`. However, I get `UNDEFINED` on hover instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"];
    $("#slideshow").before("<ul id='slideshow-nav'></ul>")
    .cycle( {
        fx:                         "scrollVert",
        rev:                            "scrollVert",
        speed:                      600,
        timeout:                    0,
        pagerEvent:             "mouseover", 
        pager:                      "#slideshow-nav",
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
            return "<li>" + titles[index] + "</li>";
        }       
    });
     $("#slideshow-nav li").hover(function(index) {
        $(this).parent().children(".activeSlide").append("<a href='#'>" + titles[index] + "</a>");
    }, function () {
        $("a").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Simply use `titles[i]` where `i` is 0, 1 or 2 (the index of your array)

Comment: That works if I want to call the same value on every list item, but it needs to change according to the index order depending on which list item has the `.activeSlide` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("ul li").hover(function () {
    var ind = $(this).index();
    if ($(this).hasClass('activeSlide')) {
        $(this).append("<a href='#'>" + titles[ind] + "</a>");
    }
}, function () {
    $("ul li a").remove();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/K5fqT/2/)

Comment: That called all three values at once.

Comment: @ElliPetersen can you be more clear in what you want to do, it seems I didn't quite understand it right.

Comment: There are three list items. As you hover over each one, the class `.activeSlide` is added. So when each list item has the `.activeSlide` class, it needs to show the array value corresponding to its index number... Does that make sense? For example, when I hover over "Title 1", a second "Title 1" should appear next to it, but not the other two values.

Comment: @ElliPetersen do you add the class in a different `hover`?

Comment: It's added by the jQuery Cycle plugin depending on which slide is active. I've updated the OP with the code I'm trying to get to work, but returns `UNDEFINED` on hover.

Comment: @ElliPetersen you have to use `.index()` on the `li element`. I updated my answer, please take a look